# Using Tesng to test the service layer of the spring project encountered some unsolvable problems

Tags: database, spring, unit-testing, service

In the process of unit testing the service layer of the spring project, I encountered the problem that the Repository cannot be called. In the unit test, I want to call the Repository to directly manipulate the contents of the database. When I use `@SpyMock` to simulate the Repository, an error is reported. as follows:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scanResultConfigureService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scanResultConfigureRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'app.dnatask.domain.repository.ScanResultConfigureRepository#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.dnatask.domain.repository.ScanResultConfigureRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'app.dnatask.domain.repository.ScanResultConfigureRepository#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.dnatask.domain.repository.ScanResultConfigureRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.dnatask.domain.repository.ScanResultConfigureRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1221)
    ... 85 more
```

The service I need to test is as follows::

```
package app.dnatask.service;

import ...

@Slf4j
@Service
public class ScanResultConfigureService {
    @Autowired
    private ScanResultConfigureRepository scanResultConfigureRepository;

    public Boolean pushResultList(String externalname) {
        ExternalNamePO po = scanResultConfigureRepository.findLabelType(externalname);
        if(po!=null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant Repository is as follows::

```
package app.dnatask.domain.repository;

import ...

public interface ScanResultConfigureRepository extends BaseRepository<ScanResultConfigurePO, String> {
    @Query(value = "select a from dna_external_name a where a.id = ?1 ")
    ExternalNamePO findLabelType(String externalname);
}
```

The relevant test classes are as follows::

```
package appTest.dnatask.service;

import ...

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ScanResultConfigureService.class})

public class ScanResultConfigureServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private ScanResultConfigureService scanResultConfigureService;

    @SpyBean
    private ScanResultConfigureRepository scanResultConfigureRepository;

    @Test
    public void testPushResultList() {
        CheckResult cr=new CheckResult();
        Boolean flag = scanResultConfigureService.pushResultList("abc");
//        .....
    }
}
```

> I checked the information and found that many people suggested using the spring configuration file. At the time, I was not good at writing configuration files. I was more inclined to use annotations to solve this problem. I want to directly access the real database, but I encountered difficulties in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `@MockBean` instead of `@SpyBean`;

second, in integration testing, when you need to reference other classes, it is recommended to use `@SpringBootTest (Application.class)`, this method works in JUnit or TestNG